# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' Terminal

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am working with Laravel and i create migration file and when i write in terminal 'php artisan migrate' then it pops up  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' at line  $table->$table->unsignedInteger(column:'user_id');

code:

```
       public function up()
        {
        Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->$table->unsignedInteger(column:'user_id');
        $table->string(column:'title');
        $table->string(column:'slug');
        $table->string(column:'company');
        $table->string(column:'location');
        $table->string(column:'title');
        $table->logo(column:'logo')->nullable();
        $table->boolean(column:'is_highlighted')->default(value:false);
        $table->boolean(column:'is_active')->default(value:true);
        $table->text(column:'content');
        $table->string(column:'apply_link');
        $table->timestamps();
       });
        }
```

Comment: 7.4 version of php

Comment: Named arguments are new in PHP 8.

Comment: and what can i do?

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 8? Preferrably to 8.1.

Comment: i am using php 7.4 and not upgrade

Comment: `$table->$table->unsignedInteger(column:'user_id');` You've also got a double `->$table` there... You can update to PHP8, or just omit the named argument: `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');`

Comment: Then don't use named arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Named arguments are available in PHP 8.0.0. Don't use them if you're using a prior version of PHP.

```
$table->$table->unsignedInteger(column:'user_id');
```

Should be

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```